# node.js http request got connection refused error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to start a web server and test the http request/response in one node.js file.

The server is running and I can open it in my browser with ip 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'.

Also I can run 'curl http://127.0.0.1:8080' in the terminal and get response.

However, when I tried to run my js script, the output showed the connection was denied. Why is it happen and how can I resolve this issue?

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const testDirectory = 'testDirectory';
const demoDirectory = 'packages/my-react-component';

console.log('start server');
yarnRun = exec('yarn run start:demo', {
    cwd: process.cwd().toString() + '/' + testDirectory + '/' + demoDirectory + '/',
});
process.stdin.resume(); // I want my server keep alive

const localhost = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
getRequestTest = exec('curl ' + localhost);
getRequestTest.stdout.on('data', function(data)){
    console.log('stdout: ', data.toString())
}
getRequestTest.stderr.on('data', function(data)){
    console.log('stderr: ', data.toString())
}
```

The output from the curl execution in the js file is:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
```

This is the output from 'curl http://127.0.0.1:8080 -v'

```
stderr: * Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:8080/

stderr:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
stderr: *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set

stderr: * Connection failed
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused
```

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue.

Comment: post more logs, add a -v flag to the curl

Comment: updated err log. anything wrong with TCP_NODELAY?

Answer (score 2):

Try with 0.0.0.0 insted of 127.0.0.1 This is work for both either localhost and by ip also.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is when I started the server in my code, it immediately executed 'curl'. In the meantime the server had not been started yet. Therefore I got such connection denied error.

I tried to setTimeout on 'curl' for 5 seconds and the cmd successfully gave me the http response.

However I think the code looks ugly. Is there a better way to write?

```
startServer = exec('node ' + process.cwd().toString() + '/script/startServer.js');

const localhost = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
console.log('localhost: ' + localhost);

function testRequest() {
    console.log('run curl ' + localhost + ' -v');
    getRequestTest = exec('curl ' + localhost + ' -v');
    getRequestTest.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
    });
    getRequestTest.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
    });
}

setTimeout(testRequest, 5000);
```